# Audio signal processing from a CMSampleBufferRef source

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have an assetWriterAudioInput being fed a CMSampleBufferRef while recording a live video on iOS 4.1+ . What I want to accomplish is real-time processing the audio samples before handling them over to the assetWriter - save a video while mutating the audio coming from the microphone.
Any ideas on ways of doing that ?

Comment: Curious to know the answer if you solved this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my surprise, there was no need to create a new CMSampleBufferRef with the processed signal. Using the samples exposed as in the question to this: [Reading audio samples via AVAssetReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972677/reading-audio-samples-via-avassetreader) , and processing them in-place, the audio works.
There are two caveats, tho: 
1) The buffer size is very small, around 1024 samples per block, so I don't see how one could create spatial/echo effects without access to further away samples in realtime.
2) I believe CMSampleBufferRef timing information is very strict, so no time stretching would be allowed, it has to be done in-place this way.
Restriction #2 is not an issue for me, and #1 is not too cumbersome, as what I'm mostly after is pitch shifting, and that worked out very well using the Dirac LE library.