# When to release CMBlockBufferRef?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I'm reading LPCM samples from a track in the iPod library, by means of the export functionality of AV Foundation. Most of my code is borrowed from [Chris Adamson's example here](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/).

I'm setting up a new `CMBlockBufferRef` and retaining it with `CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer`. According to the apple [CFType reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRelease), I need to use `CFRelease` on any object I explicitly retain.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out where exactly to release the `CMBlockBufferRef` object. If I don't release it at all, I get a large memory leak. If I try to release it anywhere inside my loop, the app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in my GrabAudioData method. If I try to initiate and release it outside of the loop, the memory leak is still there. I've tried testing to see if the `blockBuffer` is `NULL`, before releasing but that doesn't work. Please help!

```
while (assetReader.status != AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted)
{
    if (assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading)
    {
        CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer = [readerOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

        if (nextBuffer)
        {
            AudioBufferList bufferList;
            CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
            CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(nextBuffer, NULL, &bufferList, sizeof(bufferList), NULL, NULL, kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment, &blockBuffer);

            // Using the AudioBufferList
            bufferManager->GrabAudioData(&bufferList); 

            CMSampleBufferInvalidate(nextBuffer);
            CFRelease(nextBuffer);

            // Releasing here causes a crash
            // CFRelease(blockBuffer);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Does this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972677/reading-audio-samples-via-avassetreader) help?

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've actually gone over that post over and over again, I just can't seem to get my own specific code to work. Definitely a great resource though.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problems might actually lie in what I'm doing with the data and not actually the release of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @sinn246's answer, you must also check the return of CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer:

```
OSStatus err = CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(nextBuffer, NULL, &bufferList, sizeof(bufferList), NULL, NULL, kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment, &blockBuffer);

if (!err && blockBuffer && bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData && (bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize > 0))
{
    // Using the AudioBufferList
    bufferManager->GrabAudioData(&bufferList);
}

if (blockBuffer) // Double check that what you are releasing actually exists!
{
    CFRelease(blockBuffer);
}

CMSampleBufferInvalidate(nextBuffer);
CFRelease(nextBuffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

blockBuffer is retained from nextBuffer, so it should be released BEFORE nextBuffer.