# How to use CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I was wondering how exactly I can implement the Core Media method **CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferList** in swift.

I'm following [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity) tutorial, which uses the method to get a list of AudioBuffers from a CMSampleBuffer.

I've tried over and over, but the compiler keeps giving me the generic

> Cannot invoke CMSampleBuffer...Buffer with an argument list of type
>   ...

which isn't very helpful.

I've already seen 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444000/how-do-i-call-cmsamplebuffergetaudiobufferlistwithretainedblockbuffer) StackOverflow question, but the only answer there seems to throw the exact same error I've been getting.

Basically, I just want someone to show me how to get this method to compile without errors in swift.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information to get a good answer. What error are you getting?

Comment: Check my Swift 3 answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41679322/520491

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have access to a sampleBuffer in a delegate method such as `captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)`

I've already struggled with the CMSampleBuffer methods, and I agree it is not obvious how to make them compile.

```
    var sizeOut = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(1)
    var listOut = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>.alloc(1)
    let listSize: Int = 10

    var blockBufferOut: Unmanaged<CMBlockBuffer>?


    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, sizeOut , listOut, listSize, kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFAllocatorDefault, UInt32(2), &blockBufferOut)
```

you will then need to call `takeRetainedValue`on the block buffer out, and handle your pointer to release them manually.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me. try it...

```
            let musicUrl: NSURL = mediaItemCollection.items[0].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! NSURL
            let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: musicUrl, options: nil)
            let assetOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: asset.tracks[0] as! AVAssetTrack, outputSettings: nil)

            var error : NSError?

            let assetReader: AVAssetReader = AVAssetReader(asset: asset, error: &error)

            if error != nil {
                print("Error asset Reader: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }

            assetReader.addOutput(assetOutput)
            assetReader.startReading()

            let sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef = assetOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()

            var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1, mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 0, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil))
            var blockBuffer: Unmanaged<CMBlockBuffer>? = nil


            CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
                sampleBuffer,
                nil,
                &audioBufferList,
                sizeof(audioBufferList.dynamicType), // instead of UInt(sizeof(audioBufferList.dynamicType))
                nil,
                nil,
                UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment),
                &blockBuffer
            )
```