# Audio waveform visualization in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

This is a two part question:

Using `AVAudioRecorder` is it possible to have a waveform respond to the incoming audio in real time similar to what happens when you activate siri on the iphone.  Perhaps using `averagePowerForChannel`?

Also, is there a way to gather the audio samples of a recording to render a waveform?

I know novocaine exists, but I was hoping not to use a framework.

Comment: It's possible https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView

Answer (score 2):

Does not seem possible using `AVAudioRecorder` by itself.

An alternative would be to use `AVCaptureSession` with an `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` which provides access to the raw audio buffer, from which the wave form can be read.

Most of the processing would be done in the delegate:

```
func captureOutput(AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

You would probably need to implement some sort of throttling to only process every Nth sample so that your visualiser code doesn't interfere with the audio.

`AVCaptureSession` is far more rudimentary compared to `AVAudioRecorder` - it does not provide any recording facilities by itself for example, and so if you wanted to also record the audio you would need to use an `AVAssetWriter` to save the samples.

This SO question shows how to access the sample buffers. It uses `AVAssetReader` to load a file, but the delegate is exactly the same as would be used for realtime processing:
[Reading audio samples via AVAssetReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972677/reading-audio-samples-via-avassetreader)

Comment: Would it be possible to use `AVAudioRecorder` for the recording and `AVCaptureSession` with `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` for the audio processing?