# Convert Audio sampleBuffer to NSData in wav format (without saving to file)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

To capture audio.

Is it possible to convert sampleBuffer to NSData in wav format (without saving to file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this solution to convert your CMSampleBufferRef into NSData.

this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997105/4218954

or this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311174/4218954

Comment: Thanks, the first is for AVAsset.
The 2ed is how i tried to do it, but and with data not in wav format